# Setting http response type in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to set the type of response that my server sends, but it is giving me error

```
this.garageService.garageList.subscribe((resp: ApiResp) => {
  this.garageList = resp.content
});
```

Here is the `ApiResp` interface that I created

```
export interface ApiResp {
  success: boolean;
  content: any;
}
```

here is the error that I am getting
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KPX5.png)

and here is how I am making my http request

```
  async getGaragelist() {
    try
    {
      let resp: any = await this.http.post<ApiResp>(this.baseURL + '/getAllGarages', { target: 'admin' }).toPromise()
      this.garageList.next(resp)
    }
    catch (error)
    {
      console.log('Error occurred while fetching garages: ', error);

    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the error? And what is the type of `this.garageList `?

Comment: You'll need to post where you make the API call

Comment: done adding screenhot and api request

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you need to return something(response/error), because the calls are observables.

Also better write the service as a regular angular http call and making them await in the component logic.